# ActiveMQ 5 redelivery not working after network disconnect

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-jms

**Frameworks**:

- Java 1.7.0_191 and 1.8.0_181
- Spring 4.3.18.RELEASE
- ActiveMQ 5.14.5

**Scenario**:

Two clients and a server. Client 1 loses connection (due to network disconnect). A message is sent and consumed by client 2. Client 1 regains network connection. Now I was expecting a redelivery of the message to client 1. Although client 1 works fine now (getting all new messages) there is a gap where client 1 didn't get the update messages, so the client is not trustable anymore.

Is this by design or did I configure something wrong?

**ServerBroker**:

```java
final String brokerURI = String.format("broker://(tcp://%s:%s)?brokerName=clientBroker", host, port);
final BrokerService brokerService = BrokerFactory.createBroker(brokerURI);
brokerService.setUseJmx(true);
brokerService.setDataDirectory(dataDirectory);
final LoggingBrokerPlugin loggingBrokerPlugin = new LoggingBrokerPlugin();
loggingBrokerPlugin.setLogConsumerEvents(true);
loggingBrokerPlugin.setLogProducerEvents(true);
brokerService.setPlugins(new BrokerPlugin[] { loggingBrokerPlugin });
brokerService.start();
```

**ServerProducer**:

```java
final JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
jmsTemplate.setExplicitQosEnabled(true);
jmsTemplate.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
jmsTemplate.setTimeToLive(600_000L);
final ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(ImmutableList.of("my.package", "java"));
activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(String.format("tcp://%s:%s", host, port));
jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(new PooledConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory));
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsQueueConstants.SERVER_UPDATE, new NotificationQueueEntry());
```

**ClientConsumer**:

```java
@JmsListener(destination = JmsQueueConstants.SERVER_UPDATE)
public void receive(final NotificationQueueEntry msg) {
    process(msg);
}

@Bean
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    final DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
    factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(true);
    factory.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_CONSUMER);
    factory.setConcurrency("2");
    return factory;
}

private ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory() {
    final ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTrustedPackages(ImmutableList.of("my.package", "java"));
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(String.format("failover:(tcp://%s:%s)?jms.closeTimeout=%d", host, port, 600_000));
    final RedeliveryPolicy redeliveryPolicy = new RedeliveryPolicy();
    redeliveryPolicy.setInitialRedeliveryDelay(10_000L);
    redeliveryPolicy.setRedeliveryDelay(1_000L);
    redeliveryPolicy.setMaximumRedeliveries(600);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setRedeliveryPolicy(redeliveryPolicy);
    activeMQConnectionFactory.setTransportListener(new TransportListener() {
        
        @Override
        public void onCommand(final Object command) {
        }
        
        @Override
        public void onException(final IOException error) {
            connected = false;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void transportInterupted() {
            connected = false;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void transportResumed() {
            if (!connected) {
                reconnect();
            }
        }
        
    });
    return new PooledConnectionFactory(activeMQConnectionFactory);
}
```

*connected* and *reconnect()* are just to visibly show the disconnected state in the client, not actively reconnecting the ActiveMQ connection.

**Log**:

```
2020-09-09 11:39:52,415 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-1-ip>:54049@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.b.T.Transport:241 Transport Connection to: tcp://<client-1-ip>:54049 failed: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
2020-09-09 11:39:52,416 [ActiveMQ BrokerService[clientBroker] Task-17] DEBUG o.a.a.t.tcp.TcpTransport:549 Stopping transport tcp:///<client-1-ip>:54049@1079
2020-09-09 11:39:52,417 [ActiveMQ BrokerService[clientBroker] Task-17] DEBUG o.a.a.b.TransportConnection:1233 Cleaning up connection resources: tcp://<client-1-ip>:54049
2020-09-09 11:39:56,339 [RMI TCP Connection(310)-<client-2-ip>] INFO m.p.s.DatabaseServiceImplementation:98 saving entity to database
2020-09-09 11:39:56,342 [server-pool-1-thread-16] INFO m.p.c.JmsConnectionFactoryCache:73 Create connection for address: client-2:1079
2020-09-09 11:39:56,343 [server-pool-1-thread-16] INFO m.p.s.ServerProducerImplementation:268 Send message to client-2:1079. Data: NotificationQueueEntry
2020-09-09 11:39:56,343 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:63125@1079] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:257 Removing Producer: ProducerInfo {commandId = 4, responseRequired = true, producerId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:5:1:1, destination = null, brokerPath = null, dispatchAsync = false, windowSize = 0, sentCount = 1}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,345 [ActiveMQ BrokerService[clientBroker] Task-17] DEBUG o.a.a.t.tcp.TcpTransport:549 Stopping transport tcp:///<client-2-ip>:63125@1079
2020-09-09 11:39:56,345 [server-pool-1-thread-16] DEBUG o.a.a.util.ThreadPoolUtils:155 Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@f78a38[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 0.000 seconds.
2020-09-09 11:39:56,346 [server-pool-1-thread-16] DEBUG o.a.a.t.tcp.TcpTransport:549 Stopping transport tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@63125
2020-09-09 11:39:56,348 [server-pool-1-thread-16] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:82 Sending: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, Host=client-2, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,350 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.InactivityMonitor:103 Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, Host=client-2, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,350 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652] DEBUG o.a.a.t.InactivityMonitor:103 Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, Host=client-2, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:130 Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:130 Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, Host=client-2, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:137 tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:137 tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:152 tcp://client-2/<client-2-ip>:1079@52652 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,351 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:152 tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,354 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:192 Adding Producer: ProducerInfo {commandId = 4, responseRequired = true, producerId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1, destination = null, brokerPath = null, dispatchAsync = false, windowSize = 0, sentCount = 0}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,357 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52652@1079] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:285 Sending message: ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1, destination = topic://ServerUpdate, transactionId = null, expiration = 1599644996357, timestamp = 1599644396357, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 0, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@11eb3c5, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 0, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,358 [ActiveMQ BrokerService[clientBroker] Task-18] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:428 preProcessDispatch: MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:client-2-52500-1599644321472-1:1:1:1, destination = topic://ServerUpdate, message = ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1, destination = topic://ServerUpdate, transactionId = null, expiration = 1599644996357, timestamp = 1599644396357, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1599644396358, brokerOutTime = 0, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@162a6d1, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1936, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}, redeliveryCounter = 0}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,359 [ActiveMQ BrokerService[clientBroker] Task-18] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:436 postProcessDispatch: MessageDispatch {commandId = 0, responseRequired = false, consumerId = ID:client-2-52500-1599644321472-1:1:1:1, destination = topic://ServerUpdate, message = ActiveMQObjectMessage {commandId = 5, responseRequired = true, messageId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1:1, originalDestination = null, originalTransactionId = null, producerId = ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1, destination = topic://ServerUpdate, transactionId = null, expiration = 1599644996357, timestamp = 1599644396357, arrival = 0, brokerInTime = 1599644396358, brokerOutTime = 1599644396359, correlationId = null, replyTo = null, persistent = true, type = null, priority = 4, groupID = null, groupSequence = 0, targetConsumerId = null, compressed = false, userID = null, content = org.apache.activemq.util.ByteSequence@162a6d1, marshalledProperties = null, dataStructure = null, redeliveryCounter = 0, size = 1936, properties = null, readOnlyProperties = false, readOnlyBody = false, droppable = false, jmsXGroupFirstForConsumer = false}, redeliveryCounter = 0}
2020-09-09 11:39:56,419 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52501@1079] INFO o.a.a.b.u.LoggingBrokerPlugin:157 Acknowledging message for client ID: ID:client-2-52500-1599644321472-0:1, ID:client-2-61550-1599640739463-4:6:1:1:1
2020-09-09 11:39:56,421 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-2-ip>:52501@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.LocalTransaction:48 commit: TX:ID:client-2-52500-1599644321472-1:1:1 syncCount: 1
2020-09-09 11:41:04,215 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.InactivityMonitor:103 Using min of local: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, SizePrefixDisabled=false, CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, StackTraceEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.8.0_181, 25.181-b13, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, CacheEnabled=true, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000, ProviderVersion=5.14.5}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]} and remote: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, SizePrefixDisabled=false, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.7.0_191, 24.191-b08, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, StackTraceEnabled=true, CacheEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, ProviderVersion=3.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:41:04,215 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:130 Received WireFormat: WireFormatInfo { version=12, properties={CacheSize=1024, ProviderName=ActiveMQ, SizePrefixDisabled=false, TcpNoDelayEnabled=true, PlatformDetails=JVM: 1.7.0_191, 24.191-b08, Oracle Corporation, OS: Windows 10, 10.0, x86, StackTraceEnabled=true, CacheEnabled=true, MaxFrameSize=9223372036854775807, TightEncodingEnabled=true, MaxInactivityDuration=30000, ProviderVersion=3.2.0.0-SNAPSHOT, MaxInactivityDurationInitalDelay=10000}, magic=[A,c,t,i,v,e,M,Q]}
2020-09-09 11:41:04,215 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:137 tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079 before negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=false, stackTraceEnabled=false, tightEncodingEnabled=false, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
2020-09-09 11:41:04,216 [ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079] DEBUG o.a.a.t.WireFormatNegotiator:152 tcp:///<client-1-ip>:50446@1079 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=9223372036854775807}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behavior for a non-durable topic subscriber. When such a subscriber is not connected it will not receive any messages sent to the broker.

It's also worth noting that this is not what is typically referred to as "redelivery." Message redelivery is what happens when, for example, a message is consumed in a transaction and that transaction is rolled back and the message is then *redelivered* to the client to try again.

Comment: Seems I misunderstood "redelivery". Using durable subscribers did the trick.